# Linux: Get the real size of the files in a folder

Tags: linux, filesystems, rsync, cp, du

I have two identical folders on different systems (diff shows that they are the same). However, du, du --apparent-size or the Dolphin-size of the folders show different sizes. I think this is related to the block sizes or the way a folder is implemented in the different file systems. However, I would like to compare the sizes of all included files. Is this possible?

Comment: You want to compare the size or the content of the files? Because two files may have the same size but totally different content.

Comment: I want to compare the size. Howerver, I thought that if the content is the same, also the size has to be the same. That is why I am confused about the meaning of the output of du --apparent-size

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I know to compare files between two computers is to generate hash on first server, move the file with hashes on second server and use it to check.

```
sha2sum /path/to/files/* >file_with_hashes
```

then copy this `file_with_hashes` to second machine and exec

```
sha2sum -c file_with_hashes
```